# Monstera propagation

Tags: houseplants, indoors, propagation, monstera

I wanted to propagate my *Mostera deliciosa* but it went wrong and I cut a simple branch with no leaf node.
I put it in water but it seems like there isn't any roots yet.
Is there any way to make this work? I don't want it to die.

Comment: You need at least two internodes for each cutting.  One under the soil/water.  The other should still have a set of leaves attached to it, above the soil.   Many plant do better with two internodes below the surface and two leaf sets above.   This is four in total.  But, the bare minimum is one below and one set of leaves above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, but a leaf node is a must. An internode alone won't help. There is a chance a bare cutting may sprout a new branch with leaves, but this can take place only at the node.